# Rails has_many association returns empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Accessing inquiries that are associated with a user does not return a list of inquiries, but rather a blank array.

For instance:

```
   user = User.first 
     => [valid user]
   i = Inquiry.first 
     => [valid inquiry]
   i.user = user 
   user.inquiries
     => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

My three models:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :clients
  has_many :inquiries
end
```

client.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :name, presence: true
end
```

inquiry.rb

```
class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    validates :user_id, :client_name, presence: true
end
```

The clients and inquiries models have t.references, index: true within the migration files.

Comment: How/where are you creating your inquiries?

Comment: Right now I'm creating them in the rails console. So I'm doing something like, i = Inquiry.new, i.name = "Joe", i.user = user, i.save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just experimenting from the console, try something like this

```
user = User.first 
user.inquiries.create(whatever the params are for inquiry)

user.inquiries  # will return the inquiries, which for now is just the one in an array.
```

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference for more info

Comment: Ok, that worked as well. So to create a new inquiry I need to use the above method? I cannot use inquiry.user = user, then inquiry.save unless I set up an inverse_of relationship in my models?

Comment: It's one way to do it, I haven't used :inverse_of, but from looking at the docs that looks like another option.  The best approach will depend on your workflow and how objects get created.

Comment: IMO, you should just always set up `inverse_of` relationships to avoid reloading objects from the database unnecessarily. It won't always happen but it sometimes will and why waste the database hit? The answer provided here is definitely the right way to create in-memory object graphs, though. Do use this approach. My answer was geared at the problem presented, not at the bigger picture like this one is.

Answer (score 2):

What you're wanting can be achieved if you use the `:inverse_of` method to help rails out a bit. So define your associations like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inquiries, inverse_of: :user
end

class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :inquiries
end
```

You'll notice that the value used in the `:inverse_of` option is equivalent to the associated model's association name. This way rails knows to check that relation for the inverse model, which should allows exactly this:

```
u = User.first
i = Inquiry.first
i.user = u
u.inquiries # => [i]
```

For more on the `:inverse_of` option, search the following links for `inverse_of`:

1. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to
2. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But why does my clients model work fine without the "inverse_of" method? I can do user = User.first, user.clients and list all of the clients associated with that user. It's odd that user.inquiries is the same basic structure but requires inverse_of.

Comment: It's different because `u = User.first` loads a User object into memory. Then `i = Inquiry.first` loads an Inquiry object into memory. So `i.user = u` tells the in-memory object `i` object how to relate to User `u`, but the in-memory `u` object doesn't get told about the reverse by default. Why would it? That's now how your standard object methods work. Using `inverse_of` tells the in-memory object to set up a reciprocal in-memory relation back to the object it just got associated with.